# Relationships and keys?

Tags: sql, database-design

I am still learning this stuff and am new to it so please go easy on me lol!
the first attributes `SerialNum, PlayerID, and CompanyID` are the primary keys i think, but i do not know how to find what other keys are involved here, or the relationships for these tables, this is where I just got stuck any help would be great.

```
Games (SerialNum, Title, Release, CompanyID, Price) 

Genre (SerialNum, Title, Category, MaturityLvl)

Players (PlayerID, Gender, FirstName, LastName, SerialNum, Owned, Played)

Company (CompanyID, CompanyTitle, Address, PhoneNum)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question please its a little unclear as to what you are asking. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What *reference* are you using for "keys" (here, candidate keys) and "relationships" (here, foreign keys)? You need to learn the defintions & procedures, then apply them.

Answer (score 0):

As per your schema design, It seems that `Games` table is related to `Company` table using `CompanyID` attribute it has **one-to-many** relationship, like one company can have zero, one or many `Games` associated with it. If `SerialNum` is primary key of `Games`, then `CompanyID` is a foreign key

Similarly your `Players` table is associated with `Games` table with a `SerialNum` attribute.

You should read about E-R model and relational database,Here are some links for basics of relational database design
[link1](http://www.datanamic.com/support/lt-dez005-introduction-db-modeling.html), [link2](http://dingo.sbs.arizona.edu/~xiaolong/Database.htm)